# PHP convert URL to link in string

Tags: php, regex

```
$string1 = "You can view the full calendar at 
           http://www.something.org/calendar/57682117 
           or email: info@something.org"
$string2 = "You can view the full calendar at 
           www.something.org/calendar/57682117 
           or email: info@something.org"
```

This is the string(s) I have. What I need to do is convert the two urls to links that will link to a page, and then the emails will need to be converted to mailto: links.

I don't need to account for websites that are blahblah.com. They will always have one of these www. or http(s). I am terrible with regular expressions... so help will be appreciated!

Comment: None of those addressed how to search for just a simple site of www or http. Also, the "duplicate" searches for m.site.com and others... not relevant to what I was looking for...

Answer (score 0):

```
$output = preg_replace('_<a href="(?!mailto:)(?!tel:)[^"]+[^>]*>(.+?)</a>_', '$1', $string1);
echo '<pre>'.print_r(htmlentities($output), true).'</pre>';
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I just tested it and it doesn't produce any links or anything given the examples I provided.